# R how to print different types of variables into one txt file

Tags: r, printing

I have a lm model, a numeric vector from vif function, and some character variables.

```
gvmodel<-gvlma(lmFit)
VIF<-sqrt(vif(lmFit))
Str1<-"Original R-square=".567"
Str2<-"Cross-validated R-Square=.123"
```

I would like to print content of all into one single txt file. I tried `cat` and `capture.output`.

```
cat(gvmodel,VIF,Str1, file="E:/.../text.txt")
capture.output(paste(gvmodel,VIF,...,sep=""),file="E:/.../text.txt")
```

Obviously this did not work. Anyone how to print them into a single txt file? Thanks

Comment: `Str1<-""Original R-square=".567"` should be `Str1 <- "Original R-square=.567"` What error message is R throwing?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sink()` works. Sink a txt file path and name, run any command that produces text outputs and they will be captured in the txt file. And finally `sink()` to close.

```
 sink("E:/.../Sink.txt")
 gvmodel
 sqrt(vif(ModeName))
 sink()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `gvmodel<-gvlma(lmFit)` produces `gvlma` object. It cannot be directly printed to .txt file as such. You *can* transform it first to characters using `as.character()` option:

```
gvmodel<-gvlma(lmFit)
gvmodel <- as.character(gvmodel)
```

The result is printable for example with `cat`. So if you put all this together:

```
gvmodel<-gvlma(lmFit)
gvmodel <- as.character(gvmodel)
VIF<-sqrt(vif(lmFit))
Str1<-"Original R-square=.567"
Str2<-"Cross-validated R-Square=.123" # NB the corrected quotation marks

cat(gvmodel,VIF,Str1, file="yourfile.txt",sep="\t")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I transformed gvmodel into character and it was printed out like this: lm(formula = Murder ~ ., data = DataTraining) Murder ~ Population + Illiteracy + Income + Frost c(Alabama = 4.04095098567961, Arizona = -1.50265504165748, California = -0.0650525845054262, Colorado = 1.54774873568549, Connecticut = -3.61072262553982... Residuals and effects of every observation was printed without changing line.